# remove trailing elements from array that are equal to zero - better way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have very long array containing numbers. I need to remove trailing zeros from that array.

if my array will look like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

I want to remove everything except `[1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

I have created function that is doing what is expected, but I'm wondering if there is a build in function I could use.

```
var arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
for(i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(arr[i]==0) 
    {
        arr.pop();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Can this be done better/faster?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming:

```
var arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

You can use this shorter code:

```
while(arr[arr.length-1] === 0){ // While the last element is a 0,
    arr.pop();                  // Remove that last element
}
```

Result:

```
arr == [1,2,0,1,0,1]
```

Comment: It can be a little shorter with `while (!arr[arr.length - 1])`

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, I understand, but it looks like there are only numbers: "very long array containing numbers". So we can assume that there is nothing "bad" in array. Nevertheless, it's just a few symbols shorter.

Comment: @Cerbrus `==` will remove `false` and `null` as well, you have to use `===`

Comment: @frieder: Eh, no it doesn't. `(false == 0) === false`.

Comment: @Cerbrus I was wront about the null but `false == 0` will return `true` were as `false === 0` will return `false`. Ive just tested it: http://postimg.org/image/dltqr0799/

Comment: empty arrays break it

Comment: @kofifus: No it doesn't. `var arr = []; while(arr[arr.length-1]){console.log('foo')}` works just fine. It doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var copy = arr.slice(0);
var len = Number(copy.reverse().join('')).toString().length;
arr.length = len;

arr -> [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

how it works

`copy.reverse().join('')` becomes "00000000000000000101021"

when you convert a numerical string to number all the preceding zeroes are kicked off

```
var len  = Number(copy.reverse().join('')) becomes 101021
```

now by just counting the number i know from where i have to remove the trailing zeroes and the fastest way to delete traling elements is by resetting the length of the array.

```
arr.length = len;
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xigoq/1/edit)

Comment: I just looked at this answer and I must say it is quite interesting. I never thought about removing trailing zeros this way. I already used @Cerbrus answer, but I'll try to compare performance of this two. It's sad we can't mark multiple answers as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [0,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

My solution is:

```
arr.join('').replace(/0+$/g,'').split('').map(Number);
```

It will remove trailing zeros in the given array.

```
Result is [0,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,1];
```

If you also needed to remove leading zeros, you can adjust the regex like this:

```
arr.join('').replace(/^0+|0+$/g,'').split('').map(Number);
```

Now It will remove not only *trailing zeros*, but *leading zeros* too.

```
Result is [1,2,0,1,0,1];
```

Comment: This will remove zeros from start and the end of the array. I needed a way to remove the `trailing` zeros.

Comment: Yep, I gave more universal solution. Just remove leading zero in regex if you want to trim only trailing. In this way
arr.join('').replace(/0+$/g,'').split('').map(Number);

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is perfectly well. Just for fun here is a reducing approach.

```js
var a = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    f = a => { var b = true;
               return a.reduceRight((r,n,i) => ( b ? n && ( b = false
                                                          , r[i] = n
                                                          )
                                                   : r[i] = n
                                               , r
                                               )         
                                   , []
                                   );
             };
console.log(f(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner representing javascript at both its best and worst at the same time.

```js
var arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

arr.slice(0,arr.reduceRight(([d,l],c) => [d||c,l-!(d||c)], [false,arr.length])[1])
```

Output:

```
[ 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1 ]
```

Comment: What is the need for `slice`?

```
arr.reduceRight((acc, item) => {
    if(item === 0 && acc.length === 0) {
        return acc;
    }
    return acc.concat(item);
}, []);
```

this works as well

Answer (score 0):

A simpler immutable approach using `reduceRight`

```
const arr = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

const prunedArray = arr.reduceRight((acc, item) => {
  if(item === 0 && acc.length === 0) {
    return acc;
  }
  return acc.concat(item);
}, []);

console.log(prunedArray); // [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
```