# How to remove particular Number from an array via JS?

Tags: javascript

i have an array as below.

```
var array_numbers = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9];
```

How can all the occurrences of zero be removed from the array and get the non zero numbers in array?

```
var result_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at Array's [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete zero values from array with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817756/delete-zero-values-from-array-with-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25361799/1959948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to just filter each item through `Boolean`:

```js
const arr = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9]

console.log(arr.filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: nother wrong answer! your `arr`is still `[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9]`. aside from the fact that it would also filter all other falsy values.

Comment: @BekimBacaj it's only a "wrong answer" if you are defining a correct answer as one that necessarily mutates the original array. OP did not ask "how do I destructively remove elements from an array?", I (and others) determined that they were asking how to get from A => B (and Array.filter is a perfectly fine way of doing that). If OP assigns the result of `arr.filter` to a variable they will have their desired array.

Comment: Yes he did "remove particular number from an Array"  Doesn't mean create a new Array. And "a particular number" certainly does not mean 'remove zeros' explicitely, and of course not, any falsy values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Javascript filter function.

First, define a function that will return true if you wish to keep the value or false if you wish to remove it.  The value to check will be passed as a parameter to the function.

```
function removeZeros(value) {
  return value !== 0;
}
```

You can then use that function in the `filter` method on your array.

```
var result_numbers= array_numbers.filter(removeZeros);
```

Comment: value != 0 will also match false and null... use !==

Comment: You can also use an arrow function, which makes it all in one line.

Comment: Other note, seems this may not work for IE 11 as filter isn't available on it

Comment: Array.prototype.filter has been available since [IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: thanks, @k2snowman69 - I have fixed the comparison for strict type checking.

Comment: @k2snowman69 you still make a valid point.  this won't work on ie8 or earlier.

Comment: If anyone is still using IE8, they have my condolences. But if that is the case, just use a polyfill.

Comment: This answer is wrong! You are not filtering zeros from the original Array, you are creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
array_numbers = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9]; 

for(var x in array_numbers)array_numbers[x] === 0 ? array_numbers.splice(x,1) : 0;

/* See the result */
console.log( JSON.stringify(array_numbers) );
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Wayne's answer you can also use an [ES6 Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to simplify even further the code.

That would look like this:

```js
var array_numbers = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9]; 

console.log(array_numbers.filter(x => x !== 0));
```

And as Rob M stated `0` evaluates to false, so you can trim it down a bit more with just:

```
array_numbers.filter(x => x);
```

Example:

```js
var array_numbers = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9]; 

console.log(array_numbers.filter(x => x));
```

Note that in this last case, values that evaluate to false such as `false`, `''`, etc would also be removed.

Comment: Or just `array_numbers.filter(x => x)` since `0` is falsey

Comment: an additional wrong answer, you are not removing anything from the given array.

Comment: @BekimBacaj his example implies two different arrays, as the variables storing them have different names. So it seems unclear if he really needs the original array to be changed or if a copy will suffice.

Comment: @Isac wrong, it does not - it says "remove particular number from an Array"  Furthermore it could be any particular number..

Comment: @BekimBacaj Still unclear to me. Note the wording on it - "get the non zero numbers in array". But i'll let post owner speak for himself as to what he really needs. Furthermore in most cases a filtered copy will do just fine, it really depends on the situation.

Comment: Citing the original question here:  "How to remove particular Number from an array via JS?" as I'm not able to read it loud for you. 
Creating a copy instead of cleaning the original array - will cause trouble for the team. And using (still experimental) nonstandard syntax, does not yield usable Production code.

Comment: @BekimBacaj `array_numbers = array_numbers.filter(x => x !== 0)` there, original with the removed values. As to the Production code, if you read the answer you see that it is stated as a complement with ES6 features, therefore it may not be supported in some browsers/environments.