# How to interprete Web Audio API getByteFrequencyData 0 values?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, web-audio-api

I'm actually getting started on a small project about music visualization, using Web Audio API and D3. I use the `getByteFrequencyData()` method as follows (implementation has been modified for clarity. This is just a "setup model"):

```js
const ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
const analyzer = ctx.createAnalyser()
const src = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioPlayer)

analyzer.fftSize = 512

src.connect(analyzer)
src.connect(ctx.destination)

//...

const getFrequencyData = () => {
  audioAnimationFrameId.current = requestAnimationFrame(getFrequencyData)
  
  const bufferLength = audioAnalyzer.frequencyBinCount
  const data = new Uint8Array(bufferLength) // 256

  audioAnalyzer.getByteFrequencyData(data)

  return data
}

if (audioAnalyzer && isAudioPlaying) getFrequencyData()
```

My problem here, is that on my Uint8Array I'm getting a lot of "0" (mostly at the end of the array) which breaks my radial chart (as the D3 scale domain depends on data array length). I understood that these values represents decibels at some frequency, but is this normal to get all these zeros at the end?

I'm guessing I may have missed some configuration on my analyser, but after a lot of tests I wasn't able to find any solution... Did I miss something, or are these values correct, and finally it would be the D3 scale that I should change?

Here are my D3 scales:

```js
const angle = scaleLinear({
  domain: [0, 256], // NB: the array length
  range: [0, Math.PI * 2]
})

const radius = scaleLinear({
  domain: [0, 255], // NB: frequency data goes from 0 to 255
  range: [0, (DIAMETER / 2)]
})
```

If someone could help me to understand these strange results, it would be really great!

Thx a lot!

Comment: I don't know anything about `getByteFrequencyData`, but if you get unwanted values, you can filter out the [trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361825/5015356) for example

Answer (score 0):

See the spec for [getByteFrequencyData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata).  The formula there explains why the values are zero.  Basically at the higher frequencies, the actual dB values fall below dB_min, so it's clamped to zero.  If you don't want this and it's ok to have floating-point values, use [getFloatFrequencyData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getfloatfrequencydata).